# Why does Jim Raynor change his mind about killing Kerrigan?

Tags: starcraft

In *StarCraft*, Jim Raynor says

> "It may not be tomorrow, darlin'. It may not even happen with an army at my back. But rest assured: I'm the man who's going to kill you some day. I'll be seein' you."

In *SC2: Wings of Liberty* and in *SC2: Heart of the Swarm*, Jim is... pretty much doing the opposite of this. Is there any canon reason about why Jim changes his mind?

Comment: I haven't played HotS so this isn't an answer, but at the end of SC2:WoL it is pretty clear that he had thought Kerrigan beyond redemption or recovery but received a new tool that cast doubt on that belief.

Comment: I'm with @DampeS8N - the discovery of the anti-Zergification artifact changed a lot of things.  Plus, it's possible to talk big in the heat of the moment, and then have your heart soften when you're faced with actually doing it.

Comment: I know in the core SC2 game, Kerrigan is actually cured and in HotS turned back into the Queen of Blades, but becomes so with much more humanity and decides to stop trying to destroy humanity.  When she's cured, Raynor remembers how much he loved her, which is also why he decides to not kill her at the end of SC2.

Comment: Her zergification isnt why he hated her, just what caused it. Plus, even after she was humanized, she zergified herself AGAIN and I'm just really confused on where this odd love story came from, because beyond the first few terran missions, ryanor pretty much hates her

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - in one of the novels (Queen of Blades, maybe?) it was revealed that they had a lot going on between missions in SC1, stuff that was only hinted at in the game's dialogue. Basically, they fell in love and started boinking before Minsk left her behind.

Comment: @TomSterkenburg, you're right, he didn't hate her because she became the QoB, but rather because she was trying to destroy humanity and that included Jim, himself.  She was simply a shell of her former self and all humanity was gone in her first iteration as the QoB.  However, as I mentioned, once she was cured, her humanity returned with her and even remained after she turned back into the QoB.  Also, as Omegacron says, there are novels that delve into the relationship between these two as well.

Comment: But based on the game, Raynor never actually hated her, he was simply trying to stop her from killing every human in the galaxy.  It's made clear that he had forgiven her completely when she was cured and stopped trying to destroy humanity and that carried over after she became the QoB again.

Comment: Well, that's all well and good, but a well structured answer would be swell :)

Comment: @Omegacron only hinted? You'd have to be a moron to not  know they were in love and screwing

Comment: @cde well, I agree - it seemed pretty evident even in the original game. But I've been married 20 years now, so I've learned to say such things in a nice way.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a stronger logical plot line that can help explain why Jim Raynor chose not to pursue his goal of killing Kerrigan.

Through the Ihan Crystal given to Jim Raynor on the Hyperion, Zeratul warned Jim:

> James Raynor, I bring tidings of doom. I have pierced the veil of the future, and beheld only oblivion. Yet one spark of hope remains. You will hold her life in your hands, and though justice demands that she die for her crimes, only she can save us.

Through this Ihan Crystal, Zeratul warned Jim Raynor that Kerrigan was the key to preventing the impending disaster. He learned of the new threats of the Hybrid, and, through Zeratul's prophecies, that Kerrigan "was the only one who could save them."

When Jim Raynor was given the opportunity to save Kerrigan, partly due to what he discovered, he took the opportunity immediately. Again, logically you can combine other parts of the past storyline (he also wanted to save her to atone for his past, etc etc) too.

Source: http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Jim_Raynor

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really covered in-game (in fact, a lot of fans got upset about changes to his character).  That said, you can draw some logical plot lines between the two games.

The main thing is time.  When SC2 starts, it has been a few years since the Queen of Blades backstabbed pretty much every last person that was near her at the time.  According to SC2, she hasn't been seen in all that time.  So Kerrigan is (likely) holed up on Char where practically no one can touch her.  Raynor, with an army still recovering from all the crap she pulled, certainly can't.

So as shown in SC2, with no way to fix things and no way to eliminate Kerrigan, he starts spending more time getting his drink on.  Rage gets dulled and we get the more bitter and morose Raynor who spends his time guilt-tripping himself over the event that sets her up as the Queen of Blades, Mengsk's betrayal of her on Tarsonis (it even features in a nightmare cinematic).  It's not his fault, but it's the starting point, so he fixates on it.  Since Mengsk is going out of his way now that he's rebuilt the Dominion to tell the story of Jim Raynor the Terrorist Jackal, it's not out of Jim's way to do something about him instead.  Hell, Jim was in love with Kerrigan, so it's revenge from a different direction.

By the time Kerrigan shows herself again, Raynor is fully engaged with the artifact jobs and his momentum against Mengsk to really pin her down.  It's probably just an excuse to put off the deed, but it's enough.  The one time she might be exposed is when she takes a personal hand on Tyrador VIII, but Jim has his hands full evacuating civilians, Moebius, and cleaning their data trail.  A little more time.

Then Valerian comes forward with one way to reverse that one event that haunts him.  Of course he jumps for it.

These are easy enough connections to make, and probably just as easy to demonstrate in game, so I don't really understand why they didn't.  As such, this answer is relegated to theory, even if it's likely.

Answer (score 2):

Jim Raynor did kill her...

By which i mean it is far more likely that he pledged to kill the rampaging swarm queen responsible for the deaths of billions than the sons-of-Korhal assassin that he fell in love with.

He Killed the queen of blades when he activated the artefact when it reached full charge (by which time my left flank had almost totally collapsed (so good timing (it was hard-mode))) in doing so, reverting Kerrigan back to her true self.

Kerigan than allows the queen of blades to be reborn so that she may be granted the power to destroy the dominion. However she retains her previous personality, morals and ideals (as you will notice when you compare her transmissions from wings of liberty to her mannerisms and expressions in HOTS) however slowly begins to relapse to her primal, previous murderous queen of blades self, as illustrated by her shock at the bloody tactics and commands she uses in many of her campaigns.

I believe that a significant part of the HOTS campaign is kerigans battle to keep her identity and not relapse after she evolves to the queens form.

Also the act of killing the queen of blades through the artefact may have been enough for Jim Raynor, satisfying his vengeance perhaps?

Comment: You have any citations of this other than personal testimony?